# BFGS: $H^{(1)}$ has first row and column as zero, then all $H^{(k)}$ will follow the same.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

This was a question in one of our tests and I had no clue how to solve it.

Consider BFGS method being applied to a general non-linear optimization problem. We had to prove that if $H^{(1)}$ has first row and column as zero vectors, then all the succeeding iterates $H^{(k)}$ will have first row and column as zero vectors.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Well, I tried proving it using update rule. Once I prove it for $H^{(2)}$, the proof can be finished with induction. But things got too complicated for me and couldn't keep track of the rows and columns of the product of matrices. My intuition is that there must some easier theoretical way to prove this.